# convert a dynamic string name in a movieclip to make an addchild

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

i have to make an addchild to a movieclip, but i really don't know how to make it with a dynamic name.

for example

```
private function buttonClicked(nameOfTheButt:String):void
{
    thumbs.addChild(nameOfTheButt);
}

buttonClicked("homepage");
```

obviously there's a casting error, im tryin to make an addchild to a string...
how can i solve this problem with a fast and possibily clean way?

---

this is the real example, based on some answers i get:

```
thumbs_homepage = new MovieClip();
thumbs_casehistory = new MovieClip();
thumbs_contacts = new MovieClip();


public function showThumbs(thumbsToShow:String):void
{
    //dynamic addchild
}

showThumbs("thumbs_homepage"); //or "thumbs_contacts" or "thumbs_casehistory"
```

Comment: You don't need `<pre>/<code>` tags to format - just select the code and press CTRL-K or click that 101010 button on the toolbar above the edit text area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `"homepage"` is a property of `this` object, you can use:

```
thumbs.addChild(this[nameOfTheBtn]);
```

If it is a child of `this` object, you can do:

```
thumbs.addChild(this.getChildByName(nameOfTheBtn));
```

Comment: hi Amarghosh, thanks for the answer!
unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me.
"Property homepage not found on com.website.Thumbs and there is no default value".
my "homepage" value, is really only a string.

in as2 i wrote:
------------------------------------------------------
function buttonClicked(nameOfTheButt)
{
    thumbs.attachMovieClip(nameOfTheButt,this.getNextHighestDepth());
}

buttonClicked("hello");

trace(thumbs.hello); //my movieclip
------------------------------------------------------

thanks again

Comment: is `homepage` the name of a clip exported for actionscript - can you do a `thumbs.addChild(new homepage());`

Comment: no, mine example was not really right, im sorry.
here you can find a really ( obviously simplified ) example.

http://pastebin.com/q6rzyHGS

thanks! :)

Comment: pastebin is blocked in my office; please edit the question and add the snippet there.

Comment: Where is `thumbs_homepage` declared - inside any function or at the class level - is it a local variable? If not, `this[thumbToShow]` should work.

Comment: thumbs_homepage is a private var declared at the class level.

im declaring and istancing it, but i want to add it on the display list only when i click my button.

based on the name of the button, i will addchild the related movieclip.

Comment: If you make it a `public` variable, you can use `thumbs.addChild(this["thumbs_homepage"]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
thumbs_homepage = new MovieClip();
thumbs_homepage.name = "thumbs_homepage";

thumbs_casehistory = new MovieClip();
thumbs_casehistory.name = "thumbs_casehistory";

thumbs_contacts = new MovieClip();
thumbs_contacts.name = "thumbs_contacts";


private function buttonClicked (nameOfTheButt:String): void {

    var _instance: MovieClip = getChildByName(nameOfTheButt) as MovieClip;

    thumbs.addChild(_instance);
}


showThumbs(thumbs_homepage.name);
```

hope it helps..
regards

Comment: this solution seems to be really good for me...but how can i addchild if my movieclip are already istanced?
you can find an example here :) thanks a lot

http://pastebin.com/q6rzyHGS

Comment: `getChildByName` will not work if he has added them to `this` movieclip, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the reference to the object that contains these movieclips. Try the solutions below. Let's say that you're coding your document class like this:

```
package
{
  public class Main extends MovieClip
  {
     public var myMovie_1:MovieClip;
     public var myMovie_2:MovieClip;
     public var myMovie_3:MovieClip;

     public function Main():void
     {
        myMovie_1 = new MovieClip();
        myMovie_2 = new MovieClip();
        myMovie_3 = new MovieClip();

        this.addChildByInstanceName("myMovie_1");
     }

     public function addChildByInstanceName(p_objectInstanceName:String):DisplayObject
     {
        if(!this.contains(this["p_objectInstanceName"]))
        {
           this.addChild(this["p_objectInstanceName"]);
        } else {
           throw(new Error("You cannot add a child twice in the display list!"));
        }
        return this["p_objectInstanceName"] as DisplayObject;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the movieclip directly? Assuming "thumbs" is sprite or movieclip that already exists:

```
    
thumbs_homepage = new MovieClip();
thumbs_casehistory = new MovieClip();
thumbs_contacts = new MovieClip();

public function showThumbs(mc:MovieClip):void
{
    thumbs.addChild(mc);
}

// adds thumbs_homepage to thumbs
showThumbs(thumbs_homepage);
```